# infinite loop in quicksort java

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort

I try to realize an algorithm of quicksort, but when I run my code, it gives me an infinite loop, I don't understand, where I make mistake in partition method in my code:

```
public static int partition(int[] a, int p, int r)
{
    int x = a[p];
    int i = p;
    int j = r + 1;
    while(true)
    {
        while(a[i] < x) 
        {
            i++;
            if (i == r) break;
        }
        while(x > a[j]) 
        {
            j--;
            if (j == p) break;
        }
        if (i >= j) break;

        int tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        tmp = a[i];
    }

    int exch = a[p];
    a[p] = a[j];
    exch = a[p];

    return j;
}
```

the input data for this code:

```
private static int[] array;
private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args){
    int n, m;
    n = sc.nextInt();
    array = new int[n+1];
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i != array.length-1; i++)
        array[i] = sc.nextInt();


    for (j = 0; j !=array.length-1; i++)
        System.out.print(array[j]);
    quickSort(array,0,array.length);

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this :
{int tmp = a[i];
        a[i]=a[j];
        tmp = a[i];}
be like
int tmp = a[i];
        a[i]=a[j];
        a[j]=tmp

Comment: Are you sure this is correct `int tmp = a[i]; a[i]=a[j]; tmp = a[i];`? If you are trying to swap two array values, that's not how you do it.

Comment: Can you provide an example input to this function (values for a, p, and r) which results in non-termination?

Comment: indeed that should be `int tmp = a[i]; a[i] = a[j]; a[j] = tmp;`

Comment: The statement `int j = r+1;` feels weird. If r is the array's length, even r would cause an index error ( at `x > a[j]`). If it is the last index, access at r+1 will cause an index error.

Comment: @Narmer,@Fincio i check and correct, and it should be `int tmp = a[i]; a[i]=a[j]; a[j]= tmp;` but in this case i  still get an infinite loop

Comment: Yes I know. The infinite loop is almost surely caused by the `while(true)` which exits in `if (i >= j) break;` which operates on the indexes and not in the array values. I think we have to go deeper, but the code is really hard to read. Could you answer @tucuxi comment?

Comment: You are setting `x = a[p];` then `i = p;`. In the first while condition you have `while(a[i] < x)` which is never true thus the `while` loop is never executed. I think you have more than one error in your code :(

Comment: @Narmer, i edit my post and add the input data

Comment: Another one: `r = array.length; j = r + 1; a[j] --> IndexOutOfBoundException`. It should be `j = r - 1`. The fact that you don't get the Exception baffles me.

Comment: @Narmer, i take the algorthm of partition for quicksort from Cormen"Algorithms" and if i'm correct understand the element `x=a[p]` is a boundary element, i try to change `j = r-1`, but get again infinite loop

Comment: Think: `p = 0` and `x = a[p] = a[0] = n` is in fact a boundary element, the first. When you set `i = p = 0` you automatically have `a[i] = a[p] = a[0] = n`. In the while loop you have `a[i] < x` which resolves in `n < n` which is never true. Again, your code is full of this kind of bug and doesn't seem to be a quicksort. You shoul follow the link @Deepanchu Bedi posted and learn the true algorithm.

Comment: There are so many off-by-one possibilities here due to arbitrary-looking `+1` and `-1` things in there that I can't get my head around the code. Also, post your `quicksort(int[], int, int)`.

Comment: @G.Bach, i use next quicksort `public static void quickSort(int a[], int p, int r){
        if (p < r){
            int q = partition(a,p,r);
            quickSort(a, p, q);
            quickSort(a,q+1,r);
        }

    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are implementing the [Cormen Algorithms version of the Quicksort algorithm](http://books.google.it/books?id=NLngYyWFl_YC&pg=PA145&lpg=PA145&dq=quicksort%20from%20Cormen%20Algorithms&source=bl&ots=ByNsBH5kD6&sig=quTjsE93dgGXDglmq242HOwhBBE&hl=it&sa=X&ei=KdvQU9K4NKWAywO_1IGICw&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=quicksort%20from%20Cormen%20Algorithms&f=false).
His version goes like this (no mention of copyright infrangiment, this is found with a simple Google search):

[image]

Your version misses almost all of it. Just for example on your first two lines:

```
int x = a[p]; //Should be a[r]
int i = p; //Should be p-1
```

Check again every single step of the algorithm and only AFTER you really understood how the agorithm works retry to write the correct function.

Also your quicksort function should be recursive, which I hope you know [what it means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)).

**HINT:** There are 2 functions, one recursive (`quickSort`) and one with only one for loop  (`partition`).

---

**EDIT:** I took the wrong quicksort algorithm from the book, sorry for that. The correct one, the one you are using, is as follows:

[image]

Still you are implementing it with some very basic errors. Here are the most evident ones:

- You are using a `while` loop instead of a `do-until (do-while in
  Java)` loop, which are [very different](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html).
- You are mixing the two algorithms, swapping (wrongly as my first
  comment pointed out) two times the values when in the Hoare-Partition
  is only done once.
- You don't need the `if (i >= j) break;` and the `if (i == r) break;`
  loop end condition because, for construction of the algorithm, they
  can never happen (either if you use `a[i] < x` as breaking condition
  or `a[i] >= x` as permitting condition). This shows that you didn't
  fully understand how the algorithm works.
- `int i = p; //Should be p-1` is still wrong.

Again, check every single step of the algorithm and correct it, you are on your way! :)

**UPDATE:** I've tried the Hoare Partition with the corrections above and the output with the input `int[] a = {13,19,9,5,12,8,7,4,11,2,6,21};` after every swap is (btw this is the answer to (a) question in the book):

```
[6, 19, 9, 5, 12, 8, 7, 4, 11, 2, 13, 21]
[6, 13, 9, 5, 12, 8, 7, 4, 11, 2, 19, 21]
[6, 2, 9, 5, 12, 8, 7, 4, 11, 13, 19, 21]
[4, 2, 9, 5, 12, 8, 7, 6, 11, 13, 19, 21]
[4, 2, 6, 5, 12, 8, 7, 9, 11, 13, 19, 21]
[4, 2, 5, 6, 12, 8, 7, 9, 11, 13, 19, 21]
[2, 4, 5, 6, 12, 8, 7, 9, 11, 13, 19, 21]
[2, 4, 5, 6, 11, 8, 7, 9, 12, 13, 19, 21]
[2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 8, 7, 11, 12, 13, 19, 21]
[2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 19, 21]
```

This was solely to check if the algorithm works (maybe a print error could have caused the infinite loop).

Comment: I use another algorithm for partition-method from Cormen book : `Partition(A, p, r)
x = A[p]
i = p - 1
j = r + 1
while true
    repeat
        j = j - 1
    until A[j] <= x
    repeat
        i = i + 1
    until A[i] >= x
    if i < j
        swap( A[i], A[j] )
    else
        return j`

Comment: i found my bugs, it was output error in main() method and bugs in Horar-partition about what you wrote above. Thanks a lot for helping

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
a[j] = exch;
```

instead of

```
exch = a[p];
```

and identical bug -- thanks to @Namer and @Zhuinden -- in your code:

```
int tmp = a[i];
a[i] = a[j];
tmp = a[i];
```

Thanks to @DeepanshuBedi, [Quicksort in Java - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsQuicksort/article.html) has a description of the algorithm. It has

```
i++;
j--;
```

after the swap in the loop.

In addition, the function is expected to be recursive:

```
if (low < j)
  quicksort(low, j);
if (i < high)
  quicksort(i, high);
```

instead of your second swap.

I suggest you to copy the code from that page -- your code doesn't look to me as quicksort.

Comment: While that is an obvious error, the loop will exit shortly after; it does not explain infinite loopyness

Comment: a[j] = exch; do you mean?

Comment: I believe Narmer has found the cause (same mistake in swap within loop)

Comment: Mmmh, the infinite loop is almost surely caused by the `while(true)` which exits in `if (i >= j) break;` which operates on the indexes and not in the array values. I think we have to go deeper, but the code is really hard to read.

Comment: @Alexander Gelbukh, i try to change, but i still get an infinite loop

Answer (score -1):

[The basics of quick sort](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsQuicksort/article.html)
            try this it may solve your problem.

```
              if (i <= j) {
              tmp = a[i];
              a[i] = a[j];
              a[j] = tmp;
              i++;
              j--;}


           **int exch = a[p];
            a[p] = a[j];
            a[p] = exch;**
```

Edited your code. 
   i will suggest you to use for-loop.

```
 public static int partition(int[] a, int p, int r)
    {
        int x = a[p];
        int i = p;
        int j = r + 1;
        while(true)
        {
            while(a[i] < x) 
            {
                i++;
                if (i == r) break;
            }
            while(x > a[j]) 
            {
                j--;
                if (j == p) break;
            }
     if (i <= j) {
          tmp = a[i];
          a[i] = a[j];
          a[j] = tmp;
          i++;
          j--;}

        **int exch = a[p];
        a[p] = a[j];
        a[p] = exch;**

        return j;
    }
```

Comment: I'd advice to indicate the specific place of correction.

Comment: Well, at least show where the error was. "Edited your code. infinite loop solved" without showing and explaining the error is like not answering at all.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct `int tmp = a[i]; a[i] = a[j]; a[i] = tmp;`? If you are trying to swap two array values, that's not how you do it.